# How to sum up elements of an arraylist having type String?

Tags: string, types, arraylist, sum

I have an arraylist consisting of decimal numbers and i m supposed to take the average of last 4 elements of this arraylist.And these rational number are type of String.

private void average(String confidence) {

```
    if(myList.size() >= 4) {

    String  t = myList.get(myList.size()-1); 
    String  d = myList.get(myList.size()-2); 
    String  f = myList.get(myList.size()-3);
    String  h = myList.get(myList.size()-4);    

    String s = (t + d + f+h) ;
    long fin = Long.parseLong(s);
    long result = fin/4 ;
    System.out.println("Average is: "+result);
    }
```

but this method does not work.Could you please tell me what kind of changes am i supposed to do or any advices of doing this? Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert *before* you add. `+` on Strings means concatenate.

```
    if(myList.size() >= 4) {

    //I'm guessing all of these conf.size() calls are meant to be myList.size()
    double  t = Double.parseDouble(myList.get(conf.size()-1)); 
    double  d = Double.pareseDouble(myList.get(conf.size()-2)); 
    double  f = Double.parseDouble(myList.get(conf.size()-3));
    double  h = Double.parseDoublemyList.get(conf.size()-4));   

    double s = (t + d + f+h) ;
    double result = s/3 ; //should be 4
    System.out.println("meanAsrConfidence is: "+result);
    }
```

What you are doing now is, for example:

```
t=1, d=2, f=3, h=4
s = 1234
```

Also:

1. you need to divide by 4, not 3
2. what is `conf`? Why are you not calling `myList.size()`?
3. you're passing a String as an argument when you probably want to be passing `myList`

Comment: i converted the strings t,d,f,h to long before summing them up but still wrong???!!!

Comment: i edited my question and i changed the wrongly written parts as u said. and all of these numbers ara rational number like 7,6  4,5  4,2   0,1 .

Comment: your edit does not reflect converting BEFORE adding. You still have String types, and no parsing call.

Comment: hey, @user2052015, also I just realized I had a typo. The types of t,d,f and h were supposed to be Long once converted, not String.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the `String s = (t + d + f+h)` part. You're just appending 4 Strings right now.
You need to convert them first.

And your result will be wrong, you need to divide by 4, not 3.

Comment: i made those changes, and one more info is all of these numbers are rational numbers. And even though i first converted strings to long and then summed them up still it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Colleen's answer is good, so long as you remember to change the type to reflect what Long.parseLong() returns. I'd reply, but I'm too new.

```
if(myList.size() >= 4) {

    Double t = Double.parseLong(myList.get(conf.size()-1)); 
    Double  d = Double.pareseLong(myList.get(conf.size()-2)); 
    Double  f = Double.parseLong(myList.get(conf.size()-3));
    Double  h = Double.parseLong(myList.get(conf.size()-4));  

    Double result = (t + d + f + h) / 3 ;

    System.out.println("meanAsrConfidence is: "+result);
}
```

Comment: edited, thanks! I haven't used java in a while so I don't remember certain api information.

Comment: aaaand I also had a typo that was probably what you were actually referring to and I didn't catch it until just now

Comment: I'm pretty sure we need more information. @user2052015: What doesn't work? What is the desired output, your input, and the incorrect output?

Comment: that s the error i get:
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0.98"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't read your answer closely enough. You want to use Double.parseDouble(); -- I've updated my answer.